# Python guess the number game

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to make a guess the number game in python but whenever I guess it repeats 4 times 'your guess is too low'

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 20)
guessestaken = 0
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20 ')
guess = raw_input('Take a guess and hit enter')
while guessestaken < 4:
    guessestaken = guessestaken + 1
    if guess > number:
        print('your number is too low')
    if guess < number:
        print('your number is too high ')
    if guess == number:
        break
        print('well done the number was ' + number + ' and you got it in ' + guessestaken + '')
```

Comment: You are using print as a function without importing that from `__future__` module. Are you sure that this is p2.7 (as stated in tags), not p3k? In p2.7 you'd write `print "Hello"`, in p3k: `print("Hello")` (it's the parentheses that matters here).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the user input before the while loop.

```
guess = int(raw_input('Take a guess and hit enter'))
```

This statement should come within the while block.

The function raw_input returns a string, you should convert it to an integer. You can read more about it in the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Comment: You should IMO also add an explanation why you added the `int()` call when you edited your comment, OP might not be aware what kind of a bug he had there.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the input from the user only once, right before you enter your loop. You will need to ask the user for a new input after every iteration of the loop, otherwise the guess will never change!

Additionally, when you read in some input from the user with raw_input it will be a string. You will need to cast it to an int.
Next, if you have a break in your loop, the statements after it will not get called. This means that you need to move the break statement to after the output when the user gets the right answer, or nothing will be printed.
Lastly, your logic in the if statements is backwards, if the guess is less than your generated number then the guess was too low, not too high! Altogether you get:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 20)
guessestaken = 0
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20 ')
while guessestaken < 4:
    guess = int(raw_input('Take a guess and hit enter'))
    guessestaken = guessestaken + 1
    if guess < number:
        print('your number is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('your number is too high ')
    if guess == number:
        print('well done the number was ' + number + ' and you got it in ' + guessestaken + '')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for input *inside* your loop, otherwise you are just comparing his first guess multiple times. Also, you should convert the input value to an integer, because raw_input returns a string.

```
>>> guess = raw_input('guess the number> ')
>>> type(guess)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(int(guess))
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

from random import randint

```
print("you wanna guess a number between A to B and time of guess:")
A = int(input("A:"))
B = int(input("B:"))
time = int(input("time:"))
x = randint(1, 10)
print(x)

while time != 0:
    num = int(input("Enter: "))
    time -= 1
    if num == x:
        print("BLA BLA BLA")
        break
    print("NOPE !")
    if time == 0:
        print("game over")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You just tried to make a loop in >4 so it is a normal error just to use `while True:` and change the `raw_input` to `int(raw_input)`

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 20)
guessestaken = 0
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20 ')
guess = int(raw_input('Take a guess and hit enter'))#make your input a int
while True:#change <4 for True
    guessestaken = guessestaken + 1
    if guess > number:
        print('your number is too low')
    if guess < number:
        print('your number is too high ')
    if guess == number:
        break
        print('well done the number was ' + number + ' and you got it in ' + guessestaken + '')
```