# if goes through while closing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
answer = random.randrange(1,100)
guess = 101
while int(guess) != 0 :
    guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter 0 to exit: ')
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess <  answer :
        print('Too low')
    elif guess > answer :
        print('Too high')
    else:
        print('Correct')
print('Game closed')
```

I have to make a random number guessing game and to close the game you enter 0 it is supposed to print game closed which it does however it also prints the if < since 0 is always going to be lower than the guess how would i get it to not include the if <

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python guess the number game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293394/python-guess-the-number-game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rank your conditions in the order of preference. What takes the highest precedence? You'd want `if guess == answer` to be your first priority, because if that's the case then there's no need to check anything else and your program is done. What's your second priority? If `0` is typed then the game ends.

In other words, start with the more specific conditions (not something as broad as `guess > answer`).

Reframe your conditional statements as such:

```
if guess == answer:
    print('Correct')
    break
elif guess == 0:
    print('Game closed')
elif guess > answer:
    print('Too high')
else:
    print('Too low')
```

You also need to set `guess` to `0` to break out of the loop (or just add a `break` as I've done here)

Comment: but the game does not actually terminate when 0 is entered with this code. You need yet another `break`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes it will, since the guard of the `while` loop is now False

Comment: Oh you kept OP's `while`. Didn't see that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Re-formulate your code a bit:

```
import random


answer = random.randrange(1,100)

while True :
    guess = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter 0 to exit: '))

    if guess == 0:
        print('Game closed')
        break
    elif guess < answer :
        print('Too low')
    elif guess > answer :
        print('Too high')
    else:
        print('Correct!')
        break
```